# DatePicker NullReference exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, datepicker, nullreferenceexception

When I enable animations for my application in the `App.xaml.cs` like so:

```
RootFrame = new RadPhoneApplicationFrame { Transition = new RadContinuumAndSlideTransition() };
```

I get a `NullReference` exception when I click on a datetime picker:

> at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DataSource.GetPrevious(Object relativeTo)
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector.Balance()
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector.UpdateData()
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector.OnSizeChanged(Object
>   sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnSizeChanged(Object sender,
>   SizeChangedEventArgs e)
>   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr
>   target, UInt32 eventId, IntPtr coreEventArgs, UInt32
>   eventArgsTypeIndex)

As I saw on various websites, this is a known issue, but I didn't find a solution for this.

Could I maybe disable this animation for a single page?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using the Telerik controls, why not use the `RadDatePicker` instead of the `DatePicker` from the toolkit?

The Telerik control does not have the issue the one in the toolkit has. (I've just checked.)

If you need help using the Telerik RadDatePicker (& RadDateChooser) see http://www.telerik.com/support/videos/windows-phone-videos/getting-started-with-raddatepicker.aspx